# Hide a column if corresponding cell "is blank"/"formula is null" upon sheet's activation

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBAing but have a small amount of javascript knowledge and hoping for a bit of guidance/help as I can't seem to get the code working. There's probably some glaring mistakes so thanks for the patience.

I'm trying to get a spreadsheet to update a sheet upon that sheet's activation, where it will hide columns whose 2nd row cell is "blank" (or the formula x(y) in the cell is null).

Below is what have tried so far.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If Sh.Name = "FSM" Then
    Function hideBlankColumns()
        i = 2
        For i = 2 To 30
        If IsNull(Cells(2, i).Value) = True Then
            Columns(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        Next i            
    End Function        
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the result of your code?

Comment: You don't need the : in Else:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three errors in your code:

- you cannot define a function inside another sub.
- you are talking about hiding/unhiding columns, but in the code you hide rows: `Columns(lCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True`
- function `IsNull` always returns `False` if you pass Excel cell or its value as a parameter. In this case you should use function `IsEmpty` instead.

---

This code should work properly:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim i As Integer

    If Sh.Name = "FSM" Then
        For i = 2 To 30
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = IsEmpty(Cells(2, i).value)
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this worked except for the a formula cell can't be classed as empty, however soon as I'm hiding the cells I changed to equal 0 and hide on cell = 0. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    If Sh.Name = "FSM" Then
        lCol = 2
        Do While lCol <= ws.UsedRange.Columns.count
            If IsNull(Cells(2, lCol).Value) = True Then
                Columns(lCol).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                Columns(lCol).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
            lCol = lCol + 1
        Loop
    End if
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked except a cell cant be null when there is a formula in it, which is slightly annoying. However because I'm hiding the rows anyway I edited the formulas to yield "0" and changed your IsNull() line to

 If Cells(2, lCol) = 0 Then

instead. Ta very much!